# Python user input not workin

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure what in my code is wrong but it doesn't return the print statements. Any help is appreciated.
edit 1: Adding firstpath(input1) vs firstpath() at the end does nothing
edit 2: thanks gene for the correct response!
print("Welcome to (insert title here)\n\n")
input1 = input("You are walking down a street, and suddenly hear a loud bang. Type Y to investigate or N to ignore: ")
def firstpath(input1):
if input1 == "Y":
print("You walk towards the sound")
elif input1 == "N":
print("You continue down your path")
firstpath()

Comment: Are you calling `firstpath(input1)` anywhere? Try adding that after the code.

Comment: Looks like the indentation might just be off - the `firstpath()` at the end is within the function definition. Try tabbing that back out and including `input1` as a parameter of the function as suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

Your code maybe should've been:

```py
print("Welcome to (insert title here)\n\n")
input1 = input("You are walking down a street, and suddenly hear a loud bang. Type Y to investigate or N to ignore: ").lower()
def firstpath(local_input):
    if local_input == "y":
        print("You walk towards the sound")
    elif local_input == "n":
        print("You continue down your path")
    else:
        print('Sorry, bad answer.')
firstpath(input1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `firstpath()` outside the function definition.
You should also add `else` condition to your code for it to work properly.!

```py
print("Welcome to (insert title here)\n\n")
input1 = input("You are walking down a street, and suddenly hear a loud bang. Type Y to investigate or N to ignore: ")
def firstpath(input1):
    if input1 == "Y":
        print("You walk towards the sound")
    elif input1 == "N":
        print("You continue down your path")
    else:
        print("Please enter either Y or N")
firstpath(input1)
```

Comment: still did nothing

Comment: notice the `else` statement in case both don't work it should execute the else block.
Also, make sure you use capitals `Y` or `N`

Comment: the added else worked, thank you!!! I don't get what I was doing wrong tho

Comment: @CranberryJuice The `input1` global variable and the `input1` local variable is causing some ambiguity.

Comment: But how else would that work? Should I put input statements inside my function ?

Comment: @CranberryJuice Else means everything else. Like if the top two were `False`

Comment: @theX it causes ambiguity to the reader but the code executes without errors for now.

Comment: so I should always include an else? as like the backup but the function needs it?

Comment: @Genes , ah ok. But then, according to python philosophy: 'Readability counts.'. But it doesn’t matter, for now.

Comment: @CranberryJuice, you should include an `else` whenever you use nested `if statement`

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Welcome to (insert title here)\n\n")
input1 = input("You are walking down a street, and suddenly hear a loud bang. Type Y to investigate or N to ignore: ")
def firstpath(input1):
    if input1 == "Y":
        print("You walk towards the sound")
    elif input1 == "N":
        print("You continue down your path")
firstpath(input1)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kmd20/Desktop/Python Projects/textbasedadventure/gam.py", line 8, in <module>
    firstpath()
TypeError: firstpath() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input1'

Answer (score 0):

You are calling firstpath(input1) within the function. Try this:

```
print("Welcome to (insert title here)\n\n")
input1 = input("You are walking down a street, and suddenly hear a loud bang. Type Y to investigate or N to ignore: ")
def firstpath(input1):
    if input1 == "Y":
        print("You walk towards the sound")
    elif input1 == "N":
        print("You continue down your path")
firstpath(input1)
```

Comment: nope doesn't work, just ignores everything and gives me 
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: It worked for me--maybe this has something to do with the version of python you are running it in?